# How we can define polynom properly?

Tags: polynomials

$(x-2)P(x)=x^2-4$ is given.

Question is simple. Is $P(x)$ a polynomial or not?

Answer (score 5):

$P$ is not necessarily a polynomial. For example, the following (discontinuous) function works:

$$ P(x) = \begin{cases} x + 2 \quad &\text{if $x \neq 2$} \\ a \quad &\text{if $x = 2$} \end{cases} $$
where $a$ can be any real value.

Comment: I can extend my question. In your definition if  a=4 can we say this is a polynomial? I mean can we even define polynomial partially?